# How do I Contact the downvoter

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have posted an answer for this question:

[implementing OnItemClickListener, but onItemClick doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528490/implementing-onitemclicklistener-but-onitemclick-doesnt-work/15528550#15528550)

At the time I posted the answer the questioner set the `onClick` Listener for the button, so I suggested he set `setOnItemClickListener` for the `listview` instead of `onClick`.  I went outside.  When I come back after an hour I found out that the questioner edited his question and set the `ItemClickListener`.  Because of that somebody downvoted me without any reason.

How do I contact the downvoter to remove my downvote? I can delete my answer but I would like to know is there any possibility to identify downvoter.

I am not bothered about the reputation, but he should know the reason.  There should be a mechanism which doesn't reveal the identity of the downvoter, but that sends an update or notification when I comment with something like @downvoter.

Comment: Voting is anonymous. You can't find the downvoter. No one can.

Comment: @Oded is this not a valid question, why downvotes, thats frustrating.

Comment: [Voting works differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Not saying it is not a valid question. The answer is - there is no way to find the downvoter. The system has been designed that way.

Comment: @DannyBeckett my question is differnt

Comment: @Jim my question is different from what you have shown as possible duplicate

Comment: How so? Your question appears to be *I can delete my answer but I would like to know is there any possibility to identify downvoter.*. That's covered in the question I suggested this duplicates. Have you read through that question and its answers? Do you still have a question after doing so? If so, what?

Comment: In regards to the downvotes here - [votes on meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can delete my answer but I would like to know is there any possibility to identify downvoter.

There isn't.

You can either update your answer to reflect the changed question, or delete it - deleting your answer will also stop the downvote from affecting your reputation.

#### See also: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: I am not bothering about the reputation, but he should know the reason...There should be a machism that we don't know downvoter, but he can receive an update or notification when I comment with someting like @downvoter, this si not only problem

Comment: you are high reputed user, please read my question not the title, I am descriptive because of language problem..I this neither duplicate nor the invalid question

Comment: And what would that accomplish? If your answer doesn't answer the question, it doesn't really matter *why* - votes should be cast according to what *is*. Think about this: if you did change your answer to address the current question, you'd want it to be upvoted then, right? Explaining the past to the voter - who can already see the revision history if he really cares - isn't going to change what's displayed on the screen. @Pragnani

Comment: This happens to everyone sooner or later. Some folks ask questions that are unclear, and then edit to clarify them after others have already posted answers that make bad assumptions. Some folks are just jackasses, and change their questions after their initial problems are solved. See my answer to the "chameleon" question I linked to.

Comment: I have read the question and your answer..Thanks @Shog9 ...No body try to know the problem, except you..Thank you very much..Feel good talk with you..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

I thought I'd also see if it was possible via data.stackexchange

But running the following query:

```
select top 100 * from votes
where votetypeid = 3
```

Results in no UserId (that's probably on purpose).

Source: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104193/see-downvote-users

Comment: Voting data is (purposefully) anonymized before it goes into SEDE.